# 2 accounts in safe mode ?

Tags: windows-xp, safe-mode

When I start my laptop in safe mode, I have 2 accounts displayed, i.e. Administrator and one as R122, but when I start it in normal mode, only the R122 account is being displayed and not the Administrator one.

My R122 account is password protected, so once I had a problem in installation and had to go to safe mode for some reason, I was shocked to see 2 accounts.

I had once formatted my laptop with a friend of mine.

Why are there 2 accounts in safe mode and only 1 in normal mode ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows XP the local Administrator account was enabled by default. When you create another Administrator account the Local Administrator account is no longer shown on the normal logon screen. However, as you found, it still appears in Safe Mode.

In later versions of Windows this account is disabled by default.

You can disable the Local Administrator account with these [instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281140).

Comment: Thanks man. I cannot upvote you since i don't have 15 reputation. But thanks

Comment: @R122 You do now. Also, remember to accept the answer that you found the most helpful by clicking the checkmark outline next to it.

Comment: FWIW, you can re-enable the Administrator account and have it appear on your login screen by: Start -> Run -> lusrmgr.msc -> OK; Users -> Administrator -> Un-tick "Account is disabled" -> OK.  The same application will show you the other "hidden" accounts running on your PC.

Answer (score 7):

"Administrator" is a built in user account in Windows. It is always there, even if you are not in Safe Mode. Unless it's disabled.

You should have a password on that account, or disable it. Preferably disabled. Create your own administrator account and call it "Admin" or "Tech" or something similar, give it a strong password and leave it alone, to be used for emergency access and elevation purposes only. Run your main account at a lesser level. This will help in stopping viruses and malware. Disable the Guest account too. Both Guest and the built in Admin accounts are enabled by default and with no password in XP, which is a security issue.